# how to change host of ohs1 (oracle http server) in weblogic 10.3.6

Tags: linux, oracle11g, weblogic11g, oracle-fusion-middleware

I am working on weblogic server 10.3.6, I have oracle forms and reports server 11gr2 on it.
now I need to move my installation from one machine to other machine, so I need to change host of ohs1, so it can point on new machine.

In oracle enterprise manager. there is a option for port configuration but I can not find a way to change the host of web tier OHS1 (oracle http server).

I tried [chgiphost Command](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E28280_01/core.1111/e10105/host.htm#CHDCEDBC) also but it didn't work.

Is there any other option to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

If your working through OEM, go to "Advance Configuration" for your ohs1 component then select your httpd.conf file. It is here where you can specify the locations.

Hope that helps.

Regards,

V